# Validation Error as an event returned by the Domain Layer

Tags: domain-driven-design

I try to build an app using the following layers

```
Controllers <-> Application Services <-> Domain Services 
                                     <-> Infrastructure
```

Some validation might happen in the `Domain Services` and I am trying to find o a way of getting such information to the Application Service which will send it back to its caller and so on.

One way that I am trying right now is that my Domain Service would return a list of events and one of the events would by a `Validation` event.

So in my Application Service reading events I can figure out if any validation happened

**Question**:

How Ok do you thing is such strategy?

Comment: One little comment: the domain layer should not depend (in any way!) to the other layers

Comment: What happens if the validation fails? the command is rejected?

Comment: Yes. It'up to the command process code (where from the service domain was called) to decide what to do: fail and send it back to controller, retry next hour, etc

Comment: Where do you think that the Domain layers depends on other layers?

Comment: `Domain Services <-> Infrastructure`

Comment: True. I usually thinks Infrastructure as any helper for any of the layer. For example in my Domain i have some validation mechanism to check rules defined in domain layer

Comment: That is not ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66022/discussion-between-user237329-and-constantin-galbenu).

Comment: Widows Forms Applications have  Validating and Validated events. This seems like the place to call your Domain validation and handle if it failed (or succeeded).

Answer (score 1):

I assume the validation error indicates the domain service is prevented from completing the requested task. In that case an event is not appropriate. An even indicate some thing happened and other systems *may* want to react to this, but nobody is required to react.

But in this case the caller *have* to react to the error, and the result is simply not meaningful otherwise. So I think the correct approach is an exception, or some kind of Option type which indicate either a successful execution of the task or the validation error which prevented it.

Comment: I see where your going to. One of my problem with exceptions is the fact that validation is not really an exception , it's actually part of the bussiness: in domain you validate complex logic.

Comment: @user237329 Exceptions were a way of handling "this did not go as planned". You could have two kinds of problem-catchers, 1) "this was anticipated but I still have to fix it", and 2) "this was really not part of the flow the application is expected to handle". Your idea of creating events that the app receives could work, but is it more or less complex than catching all exceptions in one place? Your idea might well be better.